# Reading simple USB button and axis inputs

Tags: c#, controller, usb

I want to read simple button and axis inputs from a USB controller in C# and I have no idea how to go about it. It's just a simple USB SNES controller that I want to read inputs from. It has 8 buttons and a simple X/Y axis for the D-pad. I want to read these inputs using a timer (I already know how to use a timer, so this isn't a problem for me).

Is there any simple way to just read button presses and axis movement in C#?

Thanks!

Comment: Please expand your question with what frameworks you are using. Is this console application, WPF, are you using library like SharpDX?

Comment: I have no idea how to do it, so I have no idea what libraries to use but I'm just trying to get the inputs read so that I can put them into something like a form or something made in Blend.